# How I can jump to root on click of a button outside react navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have an icon in the header that opens a screen with stack navigator with a list view, and on pressing list item it open child/detail page. 
All working fine, what I need is when clicking on the icon again in the header it goes back to root.

NOTE: header is not part of the navigation it is a custom header
this is the screenshot if help to understand
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6sOf.png)